# Basic question on passing variables to AJAX in Wordpress

Tags: ajax

I am following an example on [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on Wordpress website. It's very simple example, and I am trying to modify the example as I intend.

What I am trying to achieve is simple:

- When a new option is selected in select/option dropdown, detect the selected value
- Pass the selected value to PHP function via AJAX

However, the selected value doesn't seem to be passed via AJAX.
The result I am getting is: whatever = 1234 | whatever2 =

How do I properly pass my variable to AJAX?

My code:

```
// Select/Option Dropdown

<select id="_type" name="_type">
  <option value="AAA"> AAA </option>
  <option value="BBB"> BBB </option>
  <option value="CCC"> CCC </option>
</select>


// Detect change and call and AJAX

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#_type'.change(function($) {
  var val = jQuery('#_type').val(); <-- Here I am properly getting val as it changes.
  console.log( '_type is changed to ' + val );

  var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'type': 'post',
    'whatever': 1234,
    'whatever2': val <-- But here val becomes empty.  
  };

  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert( 'Got this from the server: ' + response );
  });
}).change();
</script>


// PHP function 'my_action'

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
  global $wpdb;
  $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
  $whatever2 = $_POST['whatever2'];
  echo 'whatever = ' . $whatever . ' | whatever2 = ' . $whatever2;
  wp_die();
}
```

Comment: the code seems outdated but ok. Use the network monitoring tools in your browser developer tools to see what is exactly being sent and received.

Comment: I would recommend instead using the WP REST API instead of the older WP Admin AJAX system, it's a lot more explicit and as a result easier to work with, and handles a lot of stuff for you such as access levels and authentication, things that are difficult to get right with Admin AJAX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simple answer:** Don't bother with the Admin AJAX API, use the REST API!

Tell WordPress about your endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () { // register dongsan/v1/whatever
        register_rest_route( 'dongsan/v1', '/whatever/', array(
                'methods' => 'POST', // use POST to call it
                'callback' => 'dongsan_whatever' // call this function
        ) );
} );
```

Now we have an endpoint at `example.com/wp-json/dongsan/v1/whatever`!

We told WordPress to run `dongsan_whatever` when it gets called, so lets do that:

```
function dongsan_whatever( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $name = $request['name'];
    return 'hello '.$name;
}
```

Note that we used `$request['name']` to get a name parameter!

So we have a URL:

```
example.com/wp-json/dongsan/v1/whatever
```

And we can send a POST request with a name to it and get some JSON back that says Hello 'name'! So how do we do that?

Simples, it's a standard [jQuery post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request:

```
jQuery.post(
    'https://example.com/wp-json/dongsan/v1/whatever',
    { 'name': 'Dongsan' }
).done( function( data ) {
    Console.log( data ); // most likely "Hello Dongsan"
} );
```

Further reading:

- https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: I really like this Rest API approach. WP is heading to this direction, so should we. +1 for the different approach.

Comment: I followed your example, but it's yield 404 (Not Found) error, even though I copied and pasted your code. I checked the Wordpress codex page for this custom endpoint but I don't see anything wrong with your code. Still...I'm getting 404...perhaps because I am on Multisite?

Comment: After an hour of frustration, I found that it should be jQuery.post( '/blog_name/dongsan/v1/whatever' since I am on multisite environment. Now I need to figure out how to deliver this blog_name to jQuery.post...'

Comment: @Dongsan that's actually a good question! You should ask it as a separate question, it seems like something that'd get a lot of attention

Comment: I made the URL absolute so it's obvious it needs changing rather than using `/`, that should prevent others having the same problem

Comment: @TomJNowell, If I am not mistaken you function declaration syntax is of php7 and I assume it will break on earlier versions.

Comment: @MarkKaplun `add_action( '', function() {} );` is PHP 5.3 syntax not 7

Comment: sorry meant `dongsan_whatever( \WP_REST_Request $request )`

Comment: type hinting of classes is a PHP 5.0+ feature, namespaces are 5.3+, all the code written should work on PHP 5.3 and above, and 5.2 with some minor modifications

Comment: @TomJNowell Is it true that `admin-ajax` requests take longer to load and therefore basically `wp-json` is lighter in weight? BTW Rest API only answers in json right?

Comment: REST API only answers in JSON, but there's no reason for you to ever want anything else. Returning HTML is an antipattern ( and why not wrap the HTML in a json string? ). As for performance, it's arguable which of the two is faster, but I would consider admin-ajax deprecated, and use REST API all the time, afterall it will get faster with optimisation, and they're already neck and neck

Answer (score 2):

Just tested your code and it seems to be working fine. Just make sure to add a bracket to the change function `jQuery('#_type').change(function($)`

Also, you need to add `no_priv` action if you are using the ajax on frontend

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

Check and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type : 'post',` inside `data = {...}`
Also, I'm missing 'security' inside your ajax function.

Could you add this and show us the results:

```
.success( function( results ) {
                   console.log( val );
                } )
```

Comment: I added 'type' : 'post' and it's still not working. By 'security' what do you mean? The AJAX code is almost the same as the example in Wordpress AJAX in Plugin page.

Comment: Security is needed because of the `check_ajax_referer` function. [check_ajax_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer). It's not something that will fix your current issue, but it's to keep your ajax call safe.

Comment: console.log( val ) inside 'success' echoes the value properly. Very confusing.

Comment: ah, I see the problem; it's related to `my_action`. Hold on for a bit as I completely alter your code.

Comment: Dang...shame on me. I was totally wrong. The variable 'val' has values ONLY WHEN the select/option value changes. I was only looking at the first alert, which of course has val as NULL. Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: Hahaha, got it! Glad is has been solved.