# How to send get request to file.php right and where to store that file.php?

Tags: php

On w3schools or anywhere else I've seen usage of php file in link or form. But after about over 9000 times that I tried to create link with get request to php file, Wordpress did never let me make it. That's what I'm doing:

1. This is the part of Wordpress template where I'm taking values from DB and creating thumbnails with links for each value:

   ```
   <?php
   global $wpdb;
   $wp_albums = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mngr_albums ORDER BY Releasedate");

    foreach($wp_albums as $a) :
    echo '<a href="javascript: loadDoc()">' ?>

   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" name="albums">
   <div class="thumbnail col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" name="albums">

   <?php
   echo '<img src="' . $a->Image . '" width="320" height="320" alt="'. $a->Image .'">';
   echo '<br><p style="text-align: center" id="artist" name="'.$a->Artist.'">'.$a->Artist.'</p>';
   echo '<p style="text-align:center; font-size:18px" id="album" name="'.$a->Album.'">'.$a->Album.'</p>'; ?>

   </div>
   </div>
   </a>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```
2. After links were created, I'm making function with AJAX request in same template:

   ```
   <script>
   function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
    };
    var artist = document.getElementById("artist").getAttribute("name");
    var album = document.getElementById("album").getAttribute("name");
    xhttp.open("GET", "?artist=" + artist + "&album=" + album, true);
    xhttp.send();
   } 
   </script>
   ```
3. So, before get request `?artist=" + artist + "&album=" + album` I need to put link to file with this script:

   ```
   <?php

   $artist = $_REQUEST["artist"];
   $album = $_REQUEST["album"];

   $tracks = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mngr_tracks WHERE Artist = '".$artist."' AND Album = '".$album."'"); 

   echo '<ul id="list" style="z-index: 1000">';
   foreach($tracks as $t) {
   echo '<li>';
   echo '<a href="javascript: track()" id="track" name="'.$t->FileName.'">'.$t->Track.'</a>';
   echo '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>'; 

   if($_REQUEST['file'] != '') {
       $file = $_REQUEST['file'];
       echo $file;

       $p = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT FileDir FROM mngr_tracks WHERE FileName='". $file ."'"); 

       foreach ($p as $pat) {
       $path = $pat->FileDir;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Let's call script in step 3 `file.php`. Where I need to put it to make get request possible? I have tried to save it in `C:\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\this-theme` and access to it through `127.0.0.1\wordpress\wp-content\themes\this-theme\file.php?album=Album&artist=Artist` -- it never worked. Also I tried to put code from step 3 into `functions.php` and make request to it just like `\functions.php?album=Album&artist=Artist` -- nothing.

I thought that maybe `file.php` is not processed by PHP on server, but it always shows me blank page instead of code when I open `127.0.0.1\wordpress\wp-content\themes\this-theme\file.php` in browser.

Where do I need to put the `file.php`? How do I need to access to it from client side when making get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recommended, but if you want to do it, do it this way:

Save your file in your WordPress's root folder, right next to `index.php`. Then, require WordPress's core files in it, by this code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require('wp-load.php');
```

Now, even though the file is not actually a part of WordPress, it can be treated as one, and you can do anything you want with it.

However this might cause security issues, so i recommend you only try it for educational purposes.

To communicate with WordPress using AJAX, use Rest-API instead. You can find an easy solution in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262804/basic-question-on-passing-variables-to-ajax-in-wordpress) answer.